# Erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'login'

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de login, usando phpmyadmin para o banco de dados. Meu código foi desenvolvido pelo PhpStorm e os arquivos estão sendo enviados pelo FileZilla. 
Ao tentar rodar o código, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'cnsmaxi'@'localhost' to database 'login'

Esse é o trecho do código:

```
// Variáveis da conexão
$base_dados  = 'login';
$usuario_bd  = 'cnsmaxi';
$senha_bd    = '52045b2943';
$host_db     = 'localhost';
$charset_db  = 'UTF8';
$conexao_pdo = null;

// Concatenação das variáveis para detalhes da classe PDO
$detalhes_pdo  = 'mysql:host=' . $host_db . ';';
$detalhes_pdo .= 'dbname='. $base_dados . ';';
$detalhes_pdo .= 'charset=' . $charset_db . ';';
```

Comment: Esta tentando rodar em um servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troca o localhost por 127.0.0.1. 
E dê o setAttribute. 
[Documentação pdo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.connections.php)
Crie em um arquivo separado o conexao.php 
Dê o include em toda página que utiliza-lô.

```
    define("PORT", "3306");
    define("DB", "login");
    define("END", "127.0.0.1");
    define("USER", "root");
    define("PASS", "123");    
  function getConexao() {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . END . ';port=' . PORT . ';dbname=' . DB . ';charset=utf8', USER, PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}
```

Ai na chamada faça

```
$conn = getConexao();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$usuario = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**

### Update de comentários.

**
Digamos que na sua chamada esteja assim de validação.

```
$retorno =  login($_POST['Usuario'], $_POST['Senha']);
```

quando acessar o login(usuario,senha) ele retornará um booleano. Ai faça em baixo da chamada.

```
if($retorno) {
     echo 'Fez login';
else 
   echo 'Usuario ou senha invalidos';
```

Método login é este: 
no começo da página fazer o include onde tem o método getConexao();

```
  function login($login, $senha) {
            $login = mysql_escape_string($login);
            $senha = mysql_escape_string($senha);
            try {
                $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM login WHERE Login='$login' AND Senha='$senha' LIMIT 1";
                $conn = getConexao();
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                 //faça um print_r no $row para fazer o retorno...
                return true;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Esse primeiro código que você enviou foi de grande ajuda.
Mas esse segundo eu coloco ele na chamada? Pois se eu colocar no mesmo arquivo que o do primeiro, dá erro.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/gustinoco/Sislabweb/blob/master/entidade/Cliente.php
Esse é um projeto meu que faço o uso deste arquivo, note que no começo dou o include da conf e uso só o getConexao()

Comment: Aí apresenta um único arquivo. Meus arquivos estão separados. Inclusive o meu arquivo que faz a conexão é o config.php. Dentro do meu arquivo login.php, fiz o include do config e coloquei esse segundo código. E ainda apresenta erro.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda, na resposta fiz a edição.